# Boto configure s3 bucket with versioning and lifecycle

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm programmatically creating and setting up an s3 buckets with boto (2.28.0) that have both versioning and life cycle rules, auto deletes non-current versions of files after they are N days old.

Follow the example here:

> http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html

I have something like this which works great.

```
# Connect to s3.
conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key)
# Create bucket.
bucket = conn.create_bucket('example_bucket_name')

# Turn on versioning for this bucket.
bucket.configure_versioning(True)

# Add a lifecycle rules.
to_glacier = Transition(days=30, storage_class='GLACIER')
rule = Rule('ruleid', 'logs/', 'Enabled', transition=to_glacier)
lifecycle = Lifecycle()
lifecycle.append(rule)

# Configure the bucket.
bucket.configure_lifecycle(lifecycle)
```

But there doesn't seem to be support for versioned bucket rules as described here:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Basically `NoncurrentDays` and `NoncurrentVersionExpiration` rules can't be defined with boto. If I configure a bucket with these rules through the console I can look at them in boto bye getting the lifecycle, and the lifecycles have NoncurrentDays and NoncurrentVersionExpiration attributes which can be examined with.

```
lifecycle = bucket.get_lifecycle_config()
lifecycle[0].temp.NoncurrentDays
```

But adding these rules to another bucket doesn't seem to be supported.

Does anyone know if there is a work around? I assume there is a way I can manually build and attach an xml file, but I'm not seeing documentation for it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the boto releases (as of at least late 2014/2.32...) support the setting of the Noncurrent attributes.     The lifecycle.py code in boto talks only about prefix, status, and expiration.

```
    def __init__(self, id=None, prefix=None, status=None, expiration=None):
    self.id = id
    self.prefix = prefix
    self.status = status
    self.expiration = expiration
```

While not an answer to your direct question - for those searching for a work-around, the awscli tools (at least version 1.6+) support an approach like the following:
{

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket bucket-name-dev --lifecycle-configuration '{"Rules": [{"Status": "Enabled","Prefix": "","NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {"NoncurrentDays": 15}, "ID": "del_versions_15d"}]}'
```

(note the json object passed as a string)